# Oracle database - how to switch instance

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm totaly new in oracle, so sorry for my probably stupid question... I have two instances on oracle server, when I'm connecting to the server via sqlplus in default opens connection to instance X but I need to change instance to Y. How can I do that?

Comment: How exactly are you connecting via `SQL*Plus`?  Normally, you'd do something like `sqlplus user/password@TNS_alias` in which case you'd have one TNS alias for X and one for Y.  If you are telnetting to the database server and connecting without a TNS alias, your `ORACLE_SID` environment variable controls which SID is the default.  You could change that every time but it probably makes more sense to specify a TNS alias explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you already went through the steps of connecting to your Oracle DB using SQL*PLUS, here is how to switch from one database to another within your instance:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = myDB;
```

The best way (in my opinion) to connect to an specific database would be to specify the DB your are connecting to in the connection string.

```
CONNECT SYSTEM/PASSWORD@myDB
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_admin.htm#ADMIN13606

Comment: Switching the container is something different than switching the instance